# Different tmux session lists from different machines?

Tags: tmux

I have done the following:

From MachineA:

```
tmux new -s Session1
[detach from session]
tmux new -s Session2
[detach from session]
tmux ls # correctly shows Session1 and Session2
```

From MachineB:

```
ssh MachineA
tmux new -s Session3
[detach from session]
tmux ls # Only shows Session3
```

This is very confusing, as I thought connecting to the same sessions from multiple places was one of the major use cases of `tmux`. Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Tmux sessions are shared for one user. This is probably happening because you are connecting with different user.

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev Nope, I'm definitely connecting with the same user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted MachineA and everything works as expected now. Very strange...